# cordova-googlemaps-pluginで地図を画面いっぱいに表示させるには？

Tags: html, cordova

こんにちは。
現在、cordova-googlemaps-pluginでアプリ開発の練習をしています。

とりあえず画面上に地図を表示させることはできました。
その地図なのですが、画面いっぱいに表示させるにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

widthは「px」「%」「auto」どれで指定してもちゃんと表示されるのですが、
heightは「%」「auto」では反応せず、「px」指定でしか表示されません。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
  var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);
}, false);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="width:auto; height:500px;" id="map_canvas"></div>
  </box>
  </body>
</html>
```

どうぞ宜しくお願いいたします。

何が問題なのでしょう？それとも「px」でしか表示できないのでしょうか？

なにとぞご教授くださいm(__)m

Comment: コードは半角スペース4つ頭につけるかコードを選択して`{}`ボタンでハイライトすることが出来ます。質問を後から変更する場合は`編集`から直せますのでご活用ください。

Comment: ところで`html`と`body`には`height:100%`を入れてますか？

Answer (score 0):

基本的に高さにパーセントを用いる際は親要素の高さが決まってないといけません。
`html`にパーセントを用いると表示領域に対する割合の高さを指定できるため、
`html`と`body`に高さ`100%`を指定してはどうでしょうか？

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    width:240px;
    height:240px;
}
.target {
    background-color:#a0a0F0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="target">
        親に指定有り
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
    <div class="target">
        親に指定無し
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: そうでなければ、JavaScriptで画面サイズ取得して指定するしか無いですかねぇ……